# I want to get 3 highest values in output when i execute query in vb 2010

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I have a query thats displaying result, but i want 3 highest values only in Ascending order from this query

```
select (sum(l.quantity*l.rate-l.recieved)+first(c.openbal)) as total from customer c RIGHT 
JOIN ledger l ON l.refno = c.refno group by l.refno
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the **[TOP](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx)** key word for it with **[ORDER BY](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385.aspx)** Cluase

like

```
Select TOP 1 * from TABLE //Will return top most row
Select TOP 2 * from TABLE //Will return top 2 rows
Select TOP 3 * from TABLE //Will return top 3 rows
```

Your query should be

```
select TOP 3 (sum(l.quantity*l.rate-l.recieved)+first(c.openbal)) as total from customer 
c RIGHT JOIN ledger l ON l.refno = c.refno group by l.refno ORDER BY 
(sum(l.quantity*l.rate-l.recieved)+first(c.openbal)) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select TOP 3 (sum(l.quantity*l.rate-l.recieved)+first(c.openbal)) as total from customer c 
RIGHT JOIN ledger l ON l.refno = c.refno group by l.refno ORDER BY total DESC
```

Comment: i used it earlier but it displaying the top 3 values, i want 3 highest valus
@Codemunkeee

Comment: I have edited the code.. please check if it is correct

Comment: Its giving error but it worked when i replaced order by total with order by sum(l.quantity*l.rate-l.recieved)+first(c.openbal)
thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
    SELECT  SUM(Amount) as total, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY SUM(Amount) Desc) rankME
    FROM    tmp_Agents
    GROUP BY    AgentName
) x
WHERE rankME <= 3
```

Comment: thanks for your reply,
i did'nt tried it because an answer from @andy worked for me..